# Testing phpmyadmin install for Drupal in Ubuntu14.04: localhost test page not loading

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2.4, drupal

So as I have been installing my LAMP stack, I looked up my IP address at www.icanhazip.com, and attempted to load http://server-ip-address/phpmyadmin/ and it will not load the phymyadmin login page.  It just thinks and thinks and thinks...

When I go back over various ways to get Drupal running on Ubuntu14.04, there is this article:  [Install phpmyadmin in Ubuntu](http://tecadmin.net/install-phpmyadmin-in-ubuntu/)

After I supposedly "Configure Apache2 for phpmyadmin" in step 3, I am prompted to restart:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

I get the following return:

```
* Restarting web server apache2                                     [fail] 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 223 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Could not open configuration file /etc/phpmyadmin/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

This is with the end goal of creating a Drupal site with a cheap web hosting service that does not include Drupal pre-installed.  As such, I used some code of all the php packages I could need for Drupal:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-snmp php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

I got no complaints from terminal, but maybe this was too much?

One more thing, do I need hosting service to test phpmyadmin?  Is that what is meant by server-ip-address in the various descriptions of how to get phpmyadmin running?  Or just the local ip address of your machine...  I should know better, but its not working to give me feedback on which, and this type of question is breathtakingly vague for google...

Edit: I hoped that a simple purge would do it, with a different good luck charm, but it is not working.  Elsewhere on the web the combined methods were recommended, but still it posts this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

This will recover Apache.

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt php5-mysql
```

PHP installed.

http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php

Download phpMyAdmin from here, unzip, copy all files to /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/

[http://localhost/phpmyadmin/](http://http%20//localhost/phpmyadmin/)

Enter your mysql credentials.

Comment: I do not know how to create a folder using sudo in files needing root access, nor do I know how to copy over files to root access folders, or unzip things.  I tried: sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin, but the error still shows, after purging, also after adding ServerName localhost to the apache2.conf file.

Comment: just type: "sudo nautilus" it will give you a file explorer with root privileges

Comment: I was unclear about whether Mehmet intended me to copy all files to /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/, as what unzipped was another "phpmyadmin" folder with the version number, which would make it nested...  Should I remove the folder with the version name, add phpmyadmin, or extract as is, to form /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/(lots of stuff), /var/www/html/ phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin-4.3.8-all-languages/(lots of stuff),or phpMyAdmin-4.3.8-all-languages/(lots of stuff)?  Edit: I should add that I used sudo apt-get install, but folders are still empty, phpmyadmin is already installed...

Comment: [This link](http://localhost/phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin-4.3.8-all-languages/) should work then. For being more organized and proper link move all files in /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin-4.3.8-all-languages/ to upper directory.

Comment: umm, I think I will need to create a new question, but the link seems to work, but whether I shift around the contents and link this way or that way, if it works, what shows is not the homepage I have seen before, but something that starts with: addJSON( 'options', PMA_RecentTable::getInstance()->getHtmlSelectOption() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if

Comment: @ForageGarden Can you share a link or screenshot so I can see the actual problem.

Comment: You helped me isolate the problem, and I asked a separate question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/580362/most-of-steps-from-lampphpmyadmin-are-complete-yet-localhost-phpmyadmin-shows  It turns out I was missing libapache2-mod-php5, and neeeded to enter sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5.  Then I used software updater for firefox etc, re-started, and now its working, thanks!

Comment: @ForageGarden that's perfect then.