# Most of steps from LAMP>phpmyadmin are complete, yet localhost/phpmyadmin shows lots of code

Tags: server, lamp, phpmyadmin, localhost, drupal

I have installed and restarted and purged and re-installed everything 5 times over, edited .conf files, modified index.html, established htpasswd, etc... and I think I have most things ironed out, but still when I load http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ it shows a bunch of code.  I am a complete buffoon with code I haven't seen before, but the page starts out with:

```
addJSON( 'options', PMA_RecentTable::getInstance()->getHtmlSelectOption() ); exit; } if ($GLOBALS['PMA_Config']->isGitRevision()) { if
```

Blah blah General Settings, blah blah blah

I know in the past I have gotten phpmyadmin to work, but it has been a long time, but I know this can't be right...

This is a related question that I may have transcended, yet things are still not working...

[Testing phpmyadmin install for Drupal in Ubuntu14.04: localhost test page not loading](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579064/testing-phpmyadmin-install-for-drupal-in-ubuntu14-04-localhost-test-page-not-lo)

it may be interesting to note that sometimes www.icanhazip.com shows what I understand to be my public ip address, a series of 4 numbers, separated by 3 periods, or sometimes like now, it shows 8 series of alpha-numeric characters separated by 7 colons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like php is not installed, or possibly libapache2-mod-php5 is not installed but php is if you are using apache

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

That should fix all that up.

As for your ip difference, the first one is IPv4, the second is IPv6. There is a limit of ~4.3 billion IPv4 addresses possible (including private ranges etc) which the world has pretty much reached. IPv6 has about 15 quintillion addresses or something, and the internet is (very slowly) moving towards using IPv6.

Comment: I was missing libapache2-mod-php5, after using software updater and restarting ubuntu, http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ looked as I remembered it, and I successfully logged on, Yipee!

Comment: shouldn't need to restart ubuntu, you should just be able to do a sudo service apache2 restart. If you install a module or change config, generally a restart of the service is pretty much all you'll need. Glad it worked though :)

Answer (score 1):

What @drinxy told you must solved the problem.

The next time you want to make a fresh LAMP server installation I recommend you to use Tasksel. I Quote from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel:

> *"Tasksel is a Debian/Ubuntu tool that installs multiple related packages as a co-ordinated 'task' onto your system.*
>
> *This function is similar to that of meta-packages, and, in fact, most of the tasks available from tasksel are also available as meta-packages from the Ubuntu package managers (such as Synaptic Package Manager or KPackageKit)."*

To install Tasksel:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
```

Then:

```
sudo tasksel
```

And finally just follow the instructions for LAMP server. You got it.